# Get the response headers with prototype.js

Tags: javascript, header, response, prototypejs

Is there an easy way to pull out the response headers of a page with prototypejs without using `Ajax.Request`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, for the current document (i.e. the one in which the executing Javascript code was referenced).  See [various search results](http://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript+read+response+headers&btnG=Search&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&hs=ruP&sa=2).

What's your use case for this?  Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you need to do.

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer then, and now both these comments could be removed (though not by us.. we don't have high enough rep.)